# Lubuntu Disable [alt] + drag move window

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, blender, ubuntu

I've tried everything Google has to offer.  Using a computer as a dedicated Blender machine and just need a lightweight desktop.  Installed mini.iso (32-bit 14.04) and selected the "Lubuntu Minimal Installation" at install.  Exactly what I needed - hardly uses any resources to run Blender.  The Alt key, however, remains positively obstinate in its insistence to a) move the window when held with drag and b) not allow a Blender key binding in Blender's input settings.  When modifying bindings in Blender, I can hold Ctrl+Alt, click LMB and it binds just fine.  If I hold Alt and click LMB, it refuses to recognize the Alt modifier.  However, when I let up on the Alt key, it's perfectly happy to bind the action to plain Alt.  My attempts at a resolution are listed below.

Removed all traces of "A-Up/Down" bindings in rc XML files in both ~/.config/openbox/ and /etc/xdg/openbox (typing the paths from memory - hopefully these are correct).  After failed attempts here, I even deleted everything but the top-most XML tags and still no success.

Installed dconf-editor and removed the mouse modifier in org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences > mouse-button-modifier.  I understand with this one that clearing it can enable *all* buttons as modifiers so I set this to `<Shift>` just to test.

Installed CCSM and verified that the Move Window plugin was disabled.  Also, explicitly set modifier key to `Disabled`.

Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit
Lubuntu Desktop

**Update:**

I've got part of it solved.  Commented out the `<mousebind button="A-Left" action="Drag">` tag in the `<context name="Frame">` tag (was looking in the `context name="Desktop"` tag before).  This disables alt-drag in the window but I'm still unable to bint Alt+Left Click in Blender.  I've tried a) exporting the key settings, manually setting "Alt", then importing and b) searching for possible conflicts with other Alt+LMB bindings and removing.  Still no success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got it solved.  I was looking in the Desktop settings of the rc config when the settings I needed were in the "Frame" tag(`<context name="Frame">`).  Commenting out all three `<mousebind button="A-Left" action="Press/Click/Drag">` tags stopped the window from moving and allowed Alt+Left Mouse to be bound in Blender as usual.

I should also mention that I only edited the file `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and didn't modify anything in `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml`.  After the modifications, I ran `openbox --reconfigure` in the terminal and restarted just to be safe.  This was done after a clean install and no additional settings were modified, also no additional settings managers were used.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also using Lubuntu and I change the setting to `W-Left` to make use of the Window (Super) key.

Comment: Nice! Works on Lubuntu 19.04. The file is slightly different `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can also open `Window Manager Tweaks` (found through the `Application Finder`with `ALT + F3`), choose `ACcessibility` and set *Key used to grab and move windows* to `None`.